# How to get the active theme's slug?

Tags: plugins, php, themes

I'm able to get certain info about the active theme using `wp_get_theme()`. For example:

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();
echo $theme->get( 'TextDomain' ); // twentyfifteen
echo $theme->get( 'ThemeURI' ); // https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfifteen/
```

Is there a way to get the theme's slug? In this case it'd be *twentyfifteen*. Please note the theme's slug isn't always the same as the theme's text domain. I'd also like to avoid performing string replacement on the theme's URL if possible.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme

Comment: From reading through the codex, this doesn't appear to be possible without some string manipulation. It looks like it used to be, but that stuff has been deprecated. Perhaps reconsider WHY you are looking for that slug?

Comment: I need it because I'm adding theme-specific styling to a plugin I built so need a unique identifier.

Comment: @henrywright Theme specific goodies should be done in a child theme. Plugins are meant for site specific goodies ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen That's a good rule of thumb but there are exceptions :P

Comment: You have this information with get_stylesheet()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the closest thing to the theme's slug is the theme's directory name. This can be found using `get_template()`:

```
echo get_template(); // twentyfifteen
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template

Comment: That would catch the **parent** theme if there is one.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the slug in the `options` table, stored under the name `stylesheet`.

```
echo get_option('stylesheet');
```

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer: get_stylesheet();**

There is technically no 'slug' value for a theme. The name of a given theme's directory is what you want.

```
get_template();
```

…will return the directory name of your theme, ***or the parent theme*** in the case that your current theme is a child theme.

```
get_option('stylesheet');
```

Will ALWAYS return the directory name of your active theme, whether or not it is a child theme.

```
get_stylesheet();
```

Will ALWAYS return the directory name of your active theme, whether or not it is a child theme. This function is essentially a wrapper for `get_option('stylesheet');`, except that it also applies a 'stylesheet' filter.

```
function get_stylesheet() {
/**
 * Filters the name of current stylesheet.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param string $stylesheet Name of the current stylesheet.
 */
return apply_filters( 'stylesheet', get_option( 'stylesheet' ) );
}
```

I'm not sure what the 'stylesheet' filter does. Looks like it might have something to do with the customizer.

In the vast majority of cases, these three functions would do the same thing, but `get_stylesheet();` seems like the safest bet.

Answer (score 3):

`wp_get_theme` gets a [WP_Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/) object for a theme.

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();

if ( 'Conj' === $theme->name || 'conj' === $theme->template ) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_get_active_and_valid_themes()
```

i found this in wp-settings.php

```
// Load the functions for the active theme, for both parent and child theme if applicable.
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_themes() as $theme ) {
    if ( file_exists( $theme . '/functions.php' ) ) {
        include $theme . '/functions.php';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Yo can get it by `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Can you please explain how. `get_template_directory_uri()` returns a path, not a theme name

Comment: Code should be in backticks or a code block.